# Why 0.5 in value of heaviside/unitstep?

Tags: matlab

When i want to see heaviside or unit step function in matlab, as shown in attached figure. i get first value of 0.5,why 0.5? why not 1,as unit step is thought to be ?[image]

Comment: This is a purely mathematical question regarding the modified signum function. Usually, sig(x) : R->(-1,0,+1) but here, h(x): R->(0, 0.5, 1). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to understand [Stanley Pawlukiewicz](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/28715/stanley-pawlukiewicz)'s comment on the "continuous side" of Matlab's `heaviside.m`. I however think of it as a derived operator applied only on finite discrete vectors $v[n]_{1\le n\le N}$, interpreted as a discrete set of indices, with respect to their ordering (I hope I find clearer words in the times to come).

So there are two conventions for the [discrete Heaviside function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Discrete_form) (from [Oliver Heaviside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Heaviside)) at $n=0$, whose choice is significant in practice. For the continuous version of the Heaviside function, the value at $t=0$ is often deemed less important, whenever it is used under integration.

For the discrete Heaviside function, the convention you expected is:

$$ H[n]={\begin{cases}0,&n<0,\\1,&n\ge0,\end{cases}}$$

and the second one, named  the **half-maximum convention**, is:

$$ H[n]={\begin{cases}0,&n<0,\\{\tfrac {1}
{2}},&n=0,\\1,&n>0.\end{cases}}$$

There is a debate between a binary vision of the notion of signs ($\pm1$) or a ternary one: ($\pm1$ and $0$). In other words, is $0$ positive or negative? Such a choice induces a time-shift in Heaviside versions. The $1/2$ tends to provide a better symmetry: the resulting choice is symmetric around $(0,1/2)$, ie a integer sample index. And at least, it makes the convention explicit.

Comment: matlab’s Heaviside is a continuous function, part of their symbolic toolbox.

Comment: In nutshell,you mean ,it is simply convention,there can be both values possible, 1 or 0.5 at n=0??

Comment: No, choosing $0.5$ has practical impacts in practice

Answer (score 2):

Well i don't have the Symbolic Math Toolbox.  but i think i know why, and it's not a really good reason.  usually we electrical engineers mean, when we say "the **unit step**" function, we mean what math and physics people mean by the "[Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) but, there is a convention issue with what this function is with zero for its argument.

the root definition of the Heaviside unit step is

$$ H(x) \triangleq \int_{-\infty}^x { \delta(t)} \, \mathrm{d}t $$

where $\delta(t)$ is the [Dirac unit impulse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).  But this does not define $H(x)$ at $x=0$.  It's infinitesimally thin, but it could be anything finite at zero.

in continuous time, it is usually most convenient to define the Heaviside step function in terms of the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) which is:

$$\operatorname{sgn}(x) \triangleq \begin{cases} -1, & x < 0 \\ 0, & x = 0 \\ 1, & x > 0 \end{cases}$$

then the Heaviside comes out as

$$\begin{align}
 H(x) &= \tfrac12 \big(1 + \operatorname{sgn}(x) \big) \\
\\
&= \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0 \\ \tfrac12, & x = 0 \\ 1, & x > 0 \end{cases} \\
\end{align}$$

because this, $H(x) + H(-x) = 1$, is always true, they are complementary.

the problem is extending these definitions and desired behavior to discrete $x$.  then we like to define the discrete impulse as the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) which DSPer's express more simply as

$$ \delta[n] \triangleq \begin{cases} 0, & n \ne 0 \\ 1, & n = 0 \end{cases}  $$

and the **discrete unit step** as

$$ H[n] \triangleq \sum_\limits{m=-\infty}^{n} \delta[m] $$

but that makes this discrete unit step come out to be:

$$ H[n] = \begin{cases} 0, & n < 0 \\ 1, & n \ge 0 \end{cases}  $$

that is **not** quite the same as

$$\begin{align}
 H[n] &= \tfrac12 \big(1 + \operatorname{sgn}(n) \big) \\
\\
 &= \begin{cases} 0, & n < 0 \\ \tfrac12, & n = 0 \\ 1, & n > 0 \end{cases} \\
\end{align}$$

now here is the stupid problem:  MATLAB is not a continuous-time tool.  it is a discrete-time tool.

so what they are doing with the ***discrete*** Heaviside unit step function appears to me to be another one of MATLAB's mistaken conventions of definitions.  they fucked up the index origin convention which, among other problems fucked up the `fft()` convention putting the DC term into `X(1)` rather than have the index represent frequency.  they fucked up the order of polynomial coefficients in `polyval()` and `polyfit()`.  and they fucked up the definition of the **discrete** Heaviside unit step function.

EDIT: actually, they defined the Heaviside *function* correctly, because it has a continuous argument.  but they (and we) need to define a **discrete** function for the unit step that does not have $\tfrac12$ in it.

Comment: Are you referring to their way of indexing that starts with `1` instead of `0`?

Comment: that and more.  we should be able to define arrays having **any** finite origin.  i wanna be able to have negative indices so that i can represent even and odd-symmetry discrete-time signals and so the DFT can have negative frequency and so on.

Comment: While what you say makes for some nice conveniences, and I am certainly not a fan of their indexing, the functions do seem to work as intended. I mean, it's not like they are wrong, they are just rather uncomfortable to work with. But, that's just me.

Comment: the purpose of MATLAB is to represent mathematical systems in an elegant and concise manner, so that we can think mpre about our mathematical model and less about how to express it in a computer language.

Comment: Eventhough it's true that at first glance the matlab indexing starting from 1 (compared to C/C++ indexing starting from 0) irritates the user, then the rest is almost pretty consistent. The user should be aware of the distinction between mathematical objects of a continuous function, a discrete sequence, a vector, a matrix, and a physical array to store those values / samples inside computer. Nevertheless, indexing can become a headache.

Comment: @Fat32, if they did have the default indexing begin from 0 (and had the ability to change or create arrays to have negative indices as well as positive), it would make much more sense for the coefficient attached to the $x^n$ term to be `a[n]`.  that means the constant term is `a[0]`.

Comment: yes that's true. One simple solution is to indicate $n=0$ location as an object property field, but then the syntax simplicity of many operations will be lost. Afaik with the modern, object oriented codable versions of Matlab you can extend the operators and data types to create your own that would probably do that... I mean you can wrap existing build in matlab functions with extended functionality...

Comment: yeah, i guess you can do this with `subsref()` and `subsasgn()`.  i thought about trying to learn how to write a class in MATLAB.  but since i don't even count myself a C++ coder, i have sorta gotten too scared.  i would need to figure out how to overload a bunch of operators like `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `\ `, concatination and the the like.  and i would have to define a way to change the origin from 1 to another value with a function i would call `reorigin()` and to sniff the origins of an array variable with `origin()`.  it really should be done more at an atomic level.

Comment: This is a really good answer, up to where it devolves into a rant. :(

Comment: sometimes i like to rant about MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

Like the Dirac Delta, the Heaviside can be looked at as a continuous function like the error function that when you take a parameter towards a value, the continuous function appears increasingly like a step. In this march towards the step, the continuous functions all are $1/2$ at $x=0$ for something like the error function.

As the other posts point out, the value at $x=0$ is really a convention, but $1/2$ has a reasonableness to it.